# Loop Carousel horizontaly javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if somebody could help me write a loop for this carousel? at the moment the carousel just scrolls to the right every 3 seconds then scrolls back to the left afterwards and resets itself, I would just like it to contiuously loop infinitly so it looks cleaner, could somebody point me in the right direction or help me? i know its simpler but i'm not much of a js developer! (this is for google sites html box otherwise i would have used a jquery plugin)

```
<style>
 .carousel {
  width: 1080px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
 }
 .items {
  width: 1080px;
  position: absolute;
 }
 .items > div {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .items > div > img {
  padding: 10px;
 }
 .nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 15px;
 }
 .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
 }
</style>
<div class="carousel" style="display:none;">
 <div class="items">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/etisye.png" border="0" alt="Alkamai Logo">
  </div>

  <div>
   <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/ouukxu.png" border="0" alt="AWS Logo">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/16k3t43.png" border="0" alt="cover-it-live">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/23wljxh.png" border="0" alt="escenic">
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/sbiqu1.png" border="0" alt="Livefire">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/do9wep.jpg" border="0" alt="ooyala">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/24werue.png" border="0" alt="varnish">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2ij14rd.png" border="0" alt="wordpress">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
 var current_slide = 0; // zero-based
 var slide_count = 4;
 var slide_size = 1080;

 var Direction = {
  LEFT: -1,
  RIGHT: 1
 };

 /**
 * Moves to the next slide using the direction (dx) parameter.
 */
 var nextSlide = function(dx) {
  current_slide = (current_slide + slide_count + dx) % slide_count;

  // Calculate the new value for css 'left' property and animate.
  var left_offset = '-' + (current_slide * slide_size) + 'px';
  $('.items').animate({'left': left_offset}, 1080);
 };

 $('.carousel').show();

 setInterval(function(){
    nextSlide(Direction.RIGHT);
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you or anyone else trying to help: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/dWy9R/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification to your current script can make it move forward continuously.

The changes are:

1. `current_slide` is always 1 (so as to always move forward only)
2. When we move `.items` X pixels to the left, we move the corresponding number of items to the end (the number that fits inside X pixels in width)

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/dWy9R/4/

Code:

```
var parent = $('.items');

var nextSlide = function (dx) {

    // NOTE: always move forward only
    current_slide = 1; //(current_slide + slide_count + dx) % slide_count;

    // Calculate the new value for css 'left' property and animate.
    var ileft_offset = current_slide * slide_size,
        left_offset = '-' + ileft_offset + 'px',
        iWidth = 0;

    parent.animate({
        'left': left_offset
    }, 'slow', function() { // called when animation is done
        iWidth = parent.find('> div:first').width();
        while(ileft_offset > iWidth) {
            parent.find('> div:first').appendTo(parent);
            ileft_offset -= iWidth;
            parent.css('left', '-' + ileft_offset + 'px');
        }
    });
};
```

---

A modified version that doesn't pause in between. Just goes on.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/dWy9R/5/

```
var nextSlide = function () {
    parent.animate({
        'left': '-' + slide_size + 'px'
    }, 4000, 'linear', function() { // called when animation is done
        var ileft_offset = slide_size,
            iWidth = parent.find('> div:first').width();
        while(ileft_offset > iWidth) {
            parent.find('> div:first').appendTo(parent);
            ileft_offset -= iWidth;
            parent.css('left', '-' + ileft_offset + 'px');
            iWidth = parent.find('> div:first').width();
        }
        nextSlide();
    });
};

nextSlide(); // start it off!
```

Comment: Hey @techfoobar thats awesome, but is there anyway to make it smooth? as in not stop at all and just to continuously flow right?

Comment: Yeh this is great, but for some reason it breaks googles html box editor in google sites! something must be conflicting but when opening the console it shows no errors. @techfoobar